# Help with placing Photoshop file into Indesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, layers, background, file-format

Hello all the smart designers out there,

I have question regarding about importing photoshop file into Indesign layout.

I have received this product photoshop file from a photographer. When I place it into Indesign, it show anchor points around the product.

I have never seem stuff like this because the original photoshop has no mask. Just a layer with transparent background.

Do you know the reason why this is happening?

Thanks for the help! Happy Holiday!

Comment: The image frame is merely how InDesign works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it's a clipping mask, not a layer mask.

In your Photoshop layer palette you have three tabs: layers, channels and paths. Click on the paths tab and see if there's a path in there, if you click on it the points from the clipping path will show up.

If there are clipping paths in Photoshop files InDesign will import that information and use it as the edge of the image.

Answer (score 1):

InDesign is primarily a layout tool, so it has those framing tools built into the program.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e9f688c1003dbfac89-7ffca.html

This page explains the difference between the Selection tool and the Direct Selection tool. It is a little tricky to grab onto the right thing at first, but you'll soon understand how it works. Anything you place into InDesign will have the anchor points around it. If you don't care for cropping the image, just size it to match the content

This part in particular of that page I just linked goes into detail about how to differentiate the frame from the content:

> Note: An imported graphic is always contained within a frame. It’s
> possible to select the graphic and its frame, the graphic only, or its
> frame only. The frame and bounding box of an imported graphic can be
> different sizes. To see how InDesign indicates what’s selected, see
> Modifying objects using graphics frames.
>
> [image]
>
> Bounding box selected (left) compared to rectangular path selected
> (right) With rectangular objects, it can be difficult to tell the
> difference between the object’s bounding box and the path of the
> object itself. A bounding box always displays eight large hollow
> anchor points. A rectangular path always displays four small anchor
> points (which can be hollow or solid).

In short, those masks are what InDesign is all about!